# Complex Mongo Query in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

How can I use a complex mongo query in Java. for example I have this query

```
db.test_data.find({ _id: ObjectId("5877fae6761bb4555a141939") })  .forEach(function (doc) {   
doc.enrollments.forEach(function (event) {      
event.coverageenddate="0";  
 });     
db.test_data.save(doc);  
 });
```

How can I use this query in Java?

Comment: What exactly is complex about looking up a document by its id? This isn't just a query. You need to use the Mongo Java api to retrieve the document in question, then make the changes desired *in Java*, then save the document again using the API.